# Running Collection Methods on Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

Lets say I have a Post object. I want the starred ones to subsequently filter them based on some conditions.

For some years I kept doing it this way:

```
Post::where('is_starred', true)->get()->filter(function($post){ 
    ... 
});
```

This works great but today I found out that even if I remove the `get()` call it still works. I don't know exactly why this works because `where()` returns a QueryBuilder and `filter()` is a collection method. The same happens if instead a `filter()` I call some other collection methods like `each()`.

```
Post::where('is_starred', true)->filter(function($post){ 
    ... 
});
```

So my question is: Can collection methods be applied to QueryBuilder? Why? I looked at the QueryBuilder class to find out how these methods can be applied there but I didn't find anything. Is there something about that in Laravel's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. This kind of behavior happens with `each()` but `filter()`. `Eloquent\Builder` has an `each()` method which in its implementation has a call to `chunk()` which executes `get()` and apply the callback to each element.

It would be interesting to have the same for `filter()`, wouldn't it?